# FFmpeg error "track X: codec frame size is not set"

Tags: ffmpeg

I just found out about FFmpeg and I need it to cut loads of MP4 files to the last 20 seconds of each. Each MP4 file has one video track and two audio tracks.

I've been using this line of code:

```
for %F in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%F" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~nF_trimmed.mp4"
```

The trimming goes well but there's a problem with the audio. This error appears without canceling the trimming process:

```
[mp4 @ 0000025740443740] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0000025740443740] track 2: codec frame size is not set
```

Keep in mind that I'm not familiarized with coding and I just need this for video editing purposes only. I've been trying to find a way around but I had no luck. Any ideas?

If it is of use, here's the console full process:

```
D:\User Libraries\Desktop\Test>for %F in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%F" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~nF_trimmed.mp4"

D:\User Libraries\Desktop\Test>ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "Test1.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "Test1_trimmed.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-91024-g293a6e8332 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.101 / 58. 19.101
  libavformat    58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
    date            : 2018
  Duration: 00:02:57.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48706 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 48332 kb/s, 59.83 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 171 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #0, mp4, to 'Test1_trimmed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    date            : 2018
    encoder         : Lavf58.13.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 48332 kb/s, 59.83 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 171 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1211 fps=833 q=-1.0 Lsize=  124193kB time=00:00:19.98 bitrate=50911.9kbits/s speed=13.8x
video:123268kB audio:887kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.030864%

D:\User Libraries\Desktop\Test>ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "Test2.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "Test2_trimmed.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-91024-g293a6e8332 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.101 / 58. 19.101
  libavformat    58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Test2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
    date            : 2018
  Duration: 00:02:36.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49260 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 48916 kb/s, 58.73 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[mp4 @ 000001cf28f53740] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 000001cf28f53740] track 2: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'Test2_trimmed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    date            : 2018
    encoder         : Lavf58.13.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 48916 kb/s, 58.73 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1225 fps=834 q=-1.0 Lsize=  125448kB time=00:00:19.98 bitrate=51429.4kbits/s speed=13.6x
video:124591kB audio:815kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.034254%
```

Comment: Is there a problem other than those warnings?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Those are warnings and don't represent an actionable issue by themselves, because they relate to incoming metadata rather than content.

Comment: Oh. Then no, just that. The output comes up just fine, so I guess there's nothing to be done. Thanks!

PS: I have a problem with the audio though. The audio is longer than the video. Can this be caused by my files not having the codec frame size set?

Comment: the warning is coming actually from the encoder side. I get the same error mentioning mp4 when the source material is mpeg2-ts.

Answer (score 3):

An indication of the source of this warning message comes from the post
[ffmpeg MKV to MP4 error track 1: codec frame size is not set](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/404969-ffmpeg-MKV-to-MP4-error-track-1-codec-frame-size-is-not-set).

The
[answer by  Gyan](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/404969-ffmpeg-MKV-to-MP4-error-track-1-codec-frame-size-is-not-set#post2650430)
says this:

> The MP4 writer tries to determine if the audio track is VBR, for the
> purposes of the some of the further metadata it has to write. It
> checks the encoded audio frame size as part of that. The MKV writer
> does not do this.
>
> Since you're remuxing, that data isn't available for Opus, so the
> writer complains. But there is no deficiency with the file.
>
> I'll change the log level for that message - not really something for
> general users to be concerned with.

My understanding is, first, that this message is concerned with
metadata that is to be written to the header of the resulting video,
and has no impact on the correctness of the video itself.
This means that it can be ignored (the answer above says that it
should really have been omitted for end users).

Second, it means that since the video and audio are cut in an arbitrary
point, the video and audio need to be remuxed, meaning separated and
re-encoded (at least around the cutting point), and this causes the
audio encoder a problem while not having the video data available to
complement its metadata.

In any case, the final video file should be correct with no adverse
effect. You may ignore this warning,

Comment: IMHO some MP4 files (eg. generated by ffmpeg) do not generate the warnings. So this answer is a too vague since it is not describing the actual low level metadata issue.

Comment: @malat: I'm not an ffmpeg developer, so by necessity I have to depend on what can be found. All the sources I've found say this message can be ignored, but I also tried to go beyond it and to explain where it comes from, which is the audio encoder. More than that requires examining the source code of the encoder.